# obtaining attr names using mojo

Tags: perl, mojolicious

Using Mojo, how do I obtain the names of the attributes?  For example:

`<test a="1" b="2">`

I want to know that there are two attributes named 'a' and 'b'.

Answer (score 3):

Use `attr` to get attributes and their values:

```
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new('<test a="1" b="2">hello</test>');
my $t = $dom->at('test');

# save the attributes in a hash:
my $attr_h = $t->attr;
say "attributes: " . Dumper($attr_h);

# get the values for 'a' and 'b'
say "attribute a has value " . $t->attr('a');
say "attribute b has value " . $t->attr('b');
```

Output:

```
attributes: $VAR1 = {
  'b' => '2',
  'a' => '1'
};

attribute a has value 1
attribute b has value 2
```

You can obviously take the hash keys to get an array of the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

To get the attributes of a node, use [`Mojo::DOM->attr`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM#attr).

Also note, you can search for nodes having specific attribute values using [css selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump qw(dump);
use Mojo::DOM;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( do { local $/; <DATA> } );

for my $test ( $dom->find('test[a=1][b=2]')->each ) {
    print "Attributes: ", dump($test->attr), "\n";
    print "   Content: ", $test->content, "\n";
}

__DATA__
<html>
<body>
    <test a="no" b="no">First</test>
    <test a="no" b="2">Second</test>
    <test a="1" b="no">Third</test>
    <test a="1" b="2">Fourth</test>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
Attributes: { a => 1, b => 2 }
   Content: Fourth
```